# How to run insert statement on to oracle DB from shell script inside a while do loop

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, do-while

I have a use case where in my shell script I am having a do while loop and I need to insert records during this loop into oracle database. So I am expecting 3 loops and every time insert should happen. But currently my code is going into 1st loop and then inserting one record and coming out of this loop.

```
#!/bin/sh

ODATE=${1}

file_deliver_time="20210218:12:56:76"
reference_file=/var/tmp/Sneha/SSM_KPI_source_file_checklist.txt
HOME_DIR="/var/tmp/Sneha"

source ~/env/INFORMATICA.env
source ${HOME_DIR}/db.properties

runScript()
{
sql ${USER}/\"${PASS}\"@${DB_INSTANCE} @temp.sql $1 $2 $3 $4

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];
then
echo "Error";
exit 2;
fi
}

cd ${HOME_DIR}

while read -r line
do
  echo $line
  if [[ -f ${HOME_DIR}/temp.sql ]]; then rm -f ${HOME_DIR}/temp.sql; 
fi
  echo "whenever sqlerror exit failure;" > temp.sql
  echo "set define on echo on"         >> temp.sql
  echo "INSERT INTO test_ssm_kpi 
 (source_system,file_name,delivery_timestamp,ODATE) VALUES ('&1' , 
'&2' , '&3' , '&4');" >> temp.sql
 echo "exit;" >> temp.sql
 file_path=$(echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $1}' | xargs echo -n )
 file_str=$(echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $2}' | xargs echo -n )
 file_type=$(echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $3}' | xargs echo -n )
 file_source_sys=$(echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $4}' | xargs echo 
 -n )
  echo "runScript ${file_path} ${file_str} ${file_type} 
  ${file_source_sys}"
  runScript ${file_source_sys} ${file_str} ${file_type} ${ODATE}
done < $reference_file
```

The output I am getting now is as follows:

```
/var/tmp/Sneha;RTPM_POSITIONS_REPORT_;csv;ARTS
runScript /var/tmp/Sneha RTPM_POSITIONS_REPORT_ csv ARTS

SQLcl: Release 18.3 Production on Fri Nov 12 12:01:33 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Nov 12 2021 12:01:34 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.11.0.0.0

SQL> INSERT INTO test_ssm_kpi 
(source_system,file_name,delivery_timestamp,ODATE) VALUES ('&1' , '&2' , 
'&3' , '&4');
old:INSERT INTO test_ssm_kpi 
(source_system,file_name,delivery_timestamp,ODATE) VALUES ('&1' , '&2' , 
'&3' , '&4')
new:INSERT INTO test_ssm_kpi 
(source_system,file_name,delivery_timestamp,ODATE) VALUES ('ARTS' , 
'RTPM_POSITIONS_REPORT_' , 'csv' , '20211005')

1 row inserted.

SQL> exit;

Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 
19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.11.0.0.0

Note: source_file_checklist.txt this file contains 3 lines of data.

   /var/tmp/Sneha;POSITIONS_REPORT_;csv;ARTS
   /var/tmp/Sneha;SHORTPOSITION_;xml;SNK
   /var/tmp/Sneha;NETPOSITION__;xml;SNT
```

How do I make my code go through loop 3 times and in every loop it inserts a record.
I am not understanding what is missing in my shell script.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: what is the content of the reference file ? I think you don't need the second IFS, you can use `awk` to get the values of each line

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative easier to read and maintain. It is just an example in my case, but just replace the select for the insert which is in your case and your properties file configuration.

```
$ pwd
/home/ftpcpl
$ cat reference.txt
/home/ftpcpl;POSITIONS_REPORT_;csv;ARTS
/home/ftpcpl;SHORTPOSITION_;xml;SNK
/home/ftpcpl;NETPOSITION__;xml;SNT
```

Now, my test script

```
#!/bin/sh

ODATE=${1}

file_deliver_time="20210218:12:56:76"
reference_file=/home/ftpcpl/reference.txt
HOME_DIR="/home/ftpcpl"

runScript()
{
${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus "/ as sysdba" @temp.sql $1 $2 $3 $4
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];
then
  exit 2;
fi

}

cd ${HOME_DIR}

while read -r line
do
  echo $line
  if [[ -f ${HOME_DIR}/temp.sql ]]; then rm -f ${HOME_DIR}/temp.sql; fi
  echo "whenever sqlerror exit failure;" > temp.sql
  echo "set define on echo on"         >> temp.sql
  echo "select '&1' , '&2' , '&3' , '&4' from dual;" >> temp.sql
  echo "exit;" >> temp.sql
  file_path=$(echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $1}' | xargs echo -n )
  file_str=$(echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $2}' | xargs echo -n )
  file_type=$(echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $3}' | xargs echo -n )
  file_source_sys=$(echo $line | awk -F ';' '{print $4}' | xargs echo -n )
  echo "runScript ${file_path} ${file_str} ${file_type} ${file_source_sys}"
  runScript ${file_path} ${file_str} ${file_type} ${file_source_sys}
done < /home/ftpcpl/reference.txt
```

Now, let's run it

```
./test_loop.sh
/home/ftpcpl;POSITIONS_REPORT_;csv;ARTS
runScript /home/ftpcpl POSITIONS_REPORT_ csv ARTS

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Nov 9 17:17:52 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> select '&1' , '&2' , '&3' , '&4' from dual;
old   1: select '&1' , '&2' , '&3' , '&4' from dual
new   1: select '/home/ftpcpl' , 'POSITIONS_REPORT_' , 'csv' , 'ARTS' from dual

'/HOME/FTPCP 'POSITIONS_REPORT 'CS 'ART
------------ ----------------- --- ----
/home/ftpcpl POSITIONS_REPORT_ csv ARTS

SQL> exit;
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0
/home/ftpcpl;SHORTPOSITION_;xml;SNK
runScript /home/ftpcpl SHORTPOSITION_ xml SNK

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Nov 9 17:17:54 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> select '&1' , '&2' , '&3' , '&4' from dual;
old   1: select '&1' , '&2' , '&3' , '&4' from dual
new   1: select '/home/ftpcpl' , 'SHORTPOSITION_' , 'xml' , 'SNK' from dual

'/HOME/FTPCP 'SHORTPOSITION 'XM 'SN
------------ -------------- --- ---
/home/ftpcpl SHORTPOSITION_ xml SNK

SQL> exit;
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0
/home/ftpcpl;NETPOSITION__;xml;SNT
runScript /home/ftpcpl NETPOSITION__ xml SNT

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Nov 9 17:17:55 2021
Version 19.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0

SQL> select '&1' , '&2' , '&3' , '&4' from dual;
old   1: select '&1' , '&2' , '&3' , '&4' from dual
new   1: select '/home/ftpcpl' , 'NETPOSITION__' , 'xml' , 'SNT' from dual

'/HOME/FTPCP 'NETPOSITION_ 'XM 'SN
------------ ------------- --- ---
/home/ftpcpl NETPOSITION__ xml SNT

SQL> exit;
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.6.0.0.0
```

Comment: Hi @Robert Hernandez, If I run your modified script then it is not going into loop still and printing 3 times the insert statement present in temp.sql.

Comment: Hi @Robert Hernandez, also I see 3  insert statement are run onto database but but all records are same and for 1st loop itself. This again shows us it did not go into 2nd and 3rd loop to fetch next lines from the file and convert the values to new insert statement. Could you kindly let me know your further suggestions here.

Comment: show the content of the file in your question

Comment: This is the content of the file:             
 /var/tmp/Sneha;RTPM_POSITIONS_REPORT_;csv;ARTS /var/tmp/Sneha;NAKEDSHORTPOSITION_;xml;SNK  
              /var/tmp/Sneha;NETSHORTPOSITION__;xml;SNT

Comment: so it is one line, not three lines

Comment: can you post the file content using `cat` in your original question ?

Comment: Yes I have inserted the lines in the original question where it is shown in right format. Many thanks.

Comment: @Sneha, any feedback about the answer updated with the demo ? the best way to say thanks is to upvote , and if my answer solves the problem, then accept it

Comment: Hi I have not got time to look into demo and run it into my system. Apologies stuck in work meetings. I will run in sometime and provide you with feedback. :) again many thanks for all your suggestions. I will get back to you soon.

Comment: Hi @Roberto Hernandez, Apologies for commenting late on this pots. But today I tried your method, with small modification which suits my environment. And this script is still not going into 2nd and 3rd loop like yours did.  I have edited in my original question what script I am using and what output I am currently getting. Could you kindly look into this and let me know why my script is not working.

Comment: @Sneha, happy to help you but please can you upvote the answer. it is the best way to say thank you in StackOverflow

Comment: Hi @Roberto Hernandez, I clicked on the upward arrow mark on your answer, I hope this is what upvote means in your regards. Thanks again :)

Comment: that was exactly. Let me try to do a second test

Comment: Hi @Roberto Hernandez, Did you try to look into my code and understand may be why its not going into loop?  Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: @Sneha, try two things: Replace `done < $reference_file`  by `done < /var/tmp/Sneha/SSM_KPI_source_file_checklist.txt`. Instead of using sql developer command line interface, can you try sqlplus like in my example ?

Comment: I used a FOR statement and my above code worked fine and the insertion happened all 3 times. Many thanks.